# How to pass in process.stdin as Javascript with Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, stdin

I'm writing a poker game in Javascript that's supposed to take stdin as follows:

[image]

The first line of input will contain a single integer representing the number of players. This number will always be greater than 0 and less than 8.

The following n lines, where n is the number of players, will contain a single integer representing the id of the player, followed by three space-separated cards representing a hand belonging to a player.

The output, printed to stdout, will be the ID of the winning player.

[image]

But my function is in Javascript so... how do I convert this stdin to say an integer and an object like so:

```
function playPoker(n, cardsDealt){
  // functionality
}

const num = 3;
const hands = {
  '0': ['4c,', '5c', '6c'],
  '1': ['Kd', '5d,', '6d'],
  '2': ['Jc', 'Qd,', 'Ks'],
}
playPoker(num, hands);
```

I got as far as playing around with process.stdin like so but not sure how to interpret the input as Javascript:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the incoming integer to your `playPoker` function then use the count to loop through your hand generation logic, save it to an array, pass the array back, and use it to generate a formatted string and determine your winner.

```js
const playPoker = num => {
  let i = 1;
  let hands = [];

  if (!isNan(parseInt(num))) {
    while (i <= parseInt(num)) {
      let hand = [];
      // generate your hand
      hands.push(hand);
      i++;
    } 

    return hands;
  } else {
    return 'Not a valid number';
  }
}

process.stdin.on('data', data => {
  const hands = playPoker(data);
  const handsOut = hands.map(h => `${hands.indexOf(h)}: ${h[0]} ${h[1]} ${h[2]}`);
  process.stdout.write(handsOut.toString().replace(',', '\n'));

  let winner;
  // decide winner
  process.stdout.write(winner);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I realized that I can convert the data into a string and then used that to make my hands arrays.